# Recovering old tag with difflib

Tags: python, python-3.x, difflib

I am trying to recover a series of xml tags from an old version of a text (text1) and embed them in the newest version of the same text (text2).

For example:

```
text1 = "this <verb>is</verb> an example of a sentence"

text2 = "this is an <noun>example</noun> of a <noun>sentence</noun>"

desired_output = "this <verb>is</verb> an <noun>example</noun> of a <noun>sentence</noun>"
```

---

For now I have managed using difflib to print both versions seperately with the code:

```
diff = difflib.unified_diff(text1, text2, lineterm='')
print ('\n'.join(list(diff)))
```

Which gives:

```
- this <verb>is</verb> an example of a sentence
+ this is an <noun>example</noun> of a <noun>sentence</noun>
```

My question is, how can I embed the `-` string into the `+` string?

Comment: I think a good first start would be *diff*ing words instead of lines. You won't be able to this (in a general sense) with a simple line diff